# Polyfill DOM functions with babel-loader + babel/preset-env

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, babel-loader, babel-polyfill

Using Webpack 4 & babel/core 7 + babel/preset-env 7 + babel-loader 8.

Webpack rule for js files:

```
{
    test: /\.js$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
            presets: [
                [
                    '@babel/preset-env',
                    {
                        targets: ['last 1 version', 'not ie < 11'],
                        useBuiltIns: 'usage'
                    }
                ]
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

It polyfills Promises and everything, but it doesn't polyfill `ChildNode.remove()`. Including babel/polyfill didn't change anything, i guess preset-env uses babel/polyfill anyway under the hood.

So, how to polyfill DOM-Stuff?

I **don't** want to include every polyfill on my own, so "just include [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove)" is not a solution!

Maybe there even is a way to use polyfill.io together with babel/preset-env?

Comment: It's a good question and one I'm seeking the answer to, if you ever worked out a nice solution please let me know.